# How to reset Thunar File Manager?

Tags: xubuntu, filemanager, thunar

I am using Xubutu 20.04. I have observed that there might be some error in the Thunar File Manager. When I visit my videos folder, it creates thumbnails for first few rows, and then stops.
I've tried reseting it by deleting the folder at **./config** , but it doesn't seem to reset the file manager. However, when I restart my system, it works flawless, for few minutes, but again stops generating thumbnails.

Edit: It actually stops generating thumbnails for the folders of the entire system!

Answer (score 1):

Thumbnails are saved into ~/.cache/thumbnails/ and the option to enable or disable the appearance of thumbnails is in Edit > Preferences > Show Thumbnails. It is possible that it is trying to create the thumbnail for 1 particular file and stops working from then onwards, so check if you can track down which file it stops at.